# HTML page title: localization and empty title

Tags: html

2 questions about a better way of solving the problem:

1) is there is a way to make HTML page title looking different for different locales of the client-side code except for javascript?
I.e. write HTML page title which is shown in the browser's tab in corresponding language.
I know I can use javascript for this, but may be there is another way?

2)I set my HTML page header with javascript (it is a different case). But there is a delay before the script will run. Is there is a way to set HTML page header to empty line before javascript evaluates?

If I remove  tag I get the page URL.
If I use empty tag  - same thing.
I have to use &nbsp content inside which looks a bit ugly.

Some other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any other means but JavaScript on the client side for this, sorry.

For the delay: try using an inline javascript to change the page title right on top of the page before any other scripts are loaded or executed, but after the page title has been set. This should keep the delay to an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 0):

**To the first:**

Except Javascript, the only Way i know would be PHP, but using Javascript is a lot better and 
easier.

**To the second:**

arkascha's Post is the answer